# How to get a opposite background by echo

Tags: echo

If I use mode `0`,we can set the font color and background color,shuc as

```
echo -e "\e[0;31;47m teststring \e[0m"
```

[image]

But I hope to use a opposite color to be a background color(I think that is cyan).So I want to use the mode `7`(mode `7` will get a opposite background).But it don't work always:
[image]

Any body can tell me how to use this mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read carefully wikipage on [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code); you could use `\e[46m` etc

Answer (score 3):

`\e[7m` is the code for reverse video (also often used for the *standout* mode) in most terminals. What that does though is replace the background colour with the foreground colour and the foreground colour with the background colour, it's not reverse-video as in a photographic negative.

For the photographic negative, a few terminals support the:

```
\e[38;2;RED;GREEN;BLUEm  # for foreground
\e[48;2;RED;GREEN;BLUEm  # for background
```

escape sequences, where `RED`, `GREEN`, `BLUE` is a decimal number from 0 to 255. That tells the terminal to pick a colour in their palette that is closest to that RGB specification.

So you could do:

```
straight_color() {
   printf '\33[48;2;%s;%s;%sm\33[38;2;%s;%s;%sm' "$@"
}
negative_color() {
  for c do
    set -- "$@" "$((255 - c))"
    shift
  done
  straightcolor "$@"
}
```

And then for instance:

```
straight_color 255 0 0  255 255 255
```

For bright white foreground on bright red background and:

```
negative_color 255 0 0  255 255 255
```

for the negative (black on bright cyan).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to use the `terminfo` library. It's far, far easier than remembering escape codes, and usually less prone to error. (It's also terminal agnostic, but I suspect it's unlikely you'll be using a non-ANSI terminal device these days.)

```
# Use reversed colours
tput smso
echo hello, world
tput rmso
```

You can even put the codes into variables programmatically, like this

```
smso=$(tput smso)
rmso=$(tput rmso)

echo "${smso}Hello again${rmso}"
```

There are colour controls, too, using `tput setf {colour}` and `tput setb {colour}`. (Search `man terminfo` for "Color Handling".) These are more fiddly so I tend to use a little script to handle them

```
colour blue yellow
echo this is blue on yellow
```

Here's the script

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Take a pair of colours and set the foreground and background,
# respectively.
#
########################################################################
#
NULL=/dev/null

fg="$1"
bg="$2"


########################################################################
# Translate a colour name to the corresponding ANSI index value
#
colourNo ()
{
    case "$1" in
        black|0)        echo 0  ;;
        blue|1)         echo 1  ;;
        green|2)        echo 2  ;;
        cyan|3)         echo 3  ;;
        red|4)          echo 4  ;;
        magenta|5)      echo 5  ;;
        yellow|6)       echo 6  ;;
        white|7)        echo 7  ;;
    esac
    return
}


########################################################################
# Go
#
if test "X$1" = 'X-?'
then
    progname=`basename "$0"`
    echo "Usage:  $progname  [<fg_colour>|-  [bg_colour]]" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if test -n "$fg" -a "X$fg" != "X-"
then
    colour=`colourNo "$fg"`
    test -n "$colour" && tput setf "$colour"
fi

if test -n "$bg" -a "X$bg" != "X-"
then
    colour=`colourNo "$bg"`
    test -n "$colour" && tput setb "$colour"
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: If you want only reverse video, it's better to use `tput rev`. standout (smso) is usually implemented with reverse video, but not necessarily, or it could be bold+reverse for instance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you. Is the cancel operation for `rev` still `rmso`?

Comment: well, there's no dedicated capability for that, so you'd need to use `sgr0` which would revert all attributes (including color) to their default. rmso will work on terminals where rev and smso are the same but not necessarily on others (and like smso could change other attributes)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah yes of course. I'd completely forgotten about `sgr0` thank you very much.